# Можно ли сказать, что код расходует память неэффективно?

Tags: java, android, утечка-памяти, сборщик-мусора

[image: Memory monitor]

Вот кусочек аналитических данных о потреблении памяти одним Android-приложением. Как можно догадаться, резкие обрывы вниз - это срабатывания сборщика мусора Java.

Если бы "скачки" были с более резкие, то можно было бы сделать вывод о явном наличии в коде утечек памяти и в принципе о неэффктивном использовании памяти.

Но что можно сказать, исходя из этих данных? 
Можно ли однозначно сказать, насколько экономно/неэкономно здесь расходуется память?

**P.S**

Код довольно большой, приводить его не вижу смысла, однако стоит отметить, что в нем преобладают операции создания мелких "маложивущих"(до 30 секунд) объектов.

**P.P.S**

А вот этот пример(то же приложение после попыток внесения оптимизаций) можно расценивать как менее эффективное использование памяти по сравнению с примером выше:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм. По-моему, не глядя в код, ничего сказать нельзя. Получается какая-то диагностика по фотографии.

Comment: Одна лишь "фотография" не даст всеобъемлющей картины, но хотя бы даст знать о том, как часто код вынуждает сборщика мусора проходиться по выделенной памяти. Мне же как раз и интересно, нормальна ли такая частотность.

Comment: Может нормальна, а может и нет. Не уверен, что у этого вопроса существует лаконичный ответ.

Comment: Ну частое создание мелких короткоживущих объектов определенно не очень хорошо. Но не зная даже примерно для чего это делается невозможно сказать, можно ли делать это что то эффективнее.

Comment: *Но что можно сказать, исходя из этих данных? Можно ли однозначно сказать, насколько экономно/неэкономно здесь расходуется память?* - ничего. Вы правда на новый год любите гадать по геометрическим фигурам?

Comment: @xbor Всё же вроде наоборот. В java предпочтительнее короткоживущие объекты. Мало живёт - быстрее удаляется из памяти быстрым чистильщиком мусорки. Долгоживущие перемещаются в участки мусорки, которые удаляются медленным глобальным чистильщиком. Или в андроиде всё иначе?

Comment: Если GC выполняется быстро и пропуска кадров не заметно, то можно не обращать внимания. Лучше посмотреть на телефоне, где VM size  больше 32 MB, там гребни, скорее всего, будут больше

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то полагаться на сборщик мусора не есть хорошая практика. если уничтожать явно объекты, то график нужно сравнить с таким же графиком, но с более агрессивной политикой сбора мусора. Если при этом сравнении утечек тоже не будет видно, то в самом общем смысле можно будет утверждать, что утечек нет. Но вообще лучше смотреть ещё и в код, а также встраивать в него измерители

Comment: Вообще-то в `Java` нет возможности уничтожать объекты *явно*, и ничего ,кроме как полагаться на сборщик мусора, не приходится. Кроме того, он работает достаточно хорошо. Более того, вызывать вручную `System.gc()` вообще не имеет смысла исходя из алгоритма самого `GC`.

Comment: Явно - увы, нет. Но вот на английском с моей точки зрения замечательное руководство по вопросу http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404964/how-to-destroy-java-objects